# How to pass a hidden field by parameter using thymeleaf?

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

I have those hidden fields that are being updated dynamically on the screen:

```
<input type="hidden" id="orderField" name="orderField" value=""></input>
<input type="hidden" id="orderType" name="orderType" value=""></input>
```

And I have a link that calls a controller:

```
<a th:if="${!projectCentreSearchResult.readOnly}" onclick="updateOrderField()" href="#"
   th:href="@{/projectCentre/edit(projectCentreId=${projectCentreSearchResult.projectCentreId},orderField=$('#orderField').val(),orderType=$('#orderType').val())}">
    <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
</a>
```

What I need to do is to pass as parameter the orderField and orderType that I have on the hidden field. If I pass it hard coded it works fine. The thing is that I'm not being able to get it using JQuery.

Based on other fields that I have on the screen I update the hidden fields when I call the updateOrderField function. It's working fine there. The problem is that when I try to pass the parameter using JQuery it doesn't work.
I tried another approach as well by trying to pass the parameter like ${param.orderField} but it didn't work either...

What is the right way to pass it there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a form:

```
<form action="@{/projectCentre/edit}" th:action="@{/projectCentre/edit}" th:object="${your_Model}" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="orderField" name="orderField" th:value="${orderField}"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="orderType" name="orderType" th:value="${orderType}"/>
  <button name="action"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: but then I would be calling the action by post... I'd like to keep calling it by get but just passsing the other two parameters

Comment: Change the method from post to get